# Pass Python parameters to HTML

Tags: python, html

I've the following HTML code:

```
<html>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    Enter Input:
        <input type="text" class="textbox" name="usn" id="usn" required />
        <input  class="buttongo" type="submit" value="Go" />
        <input type="hidden" name="task" value="getResult"/>
    </form>
</html>
```

I want to write a python script, which executes the above HTML, passing a `value` parameter to the first input statement to the above HTML. That is,

```
<html>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    Enter Input:
        <input type="text" class="textbox" name="usn" id="usn" value="FromPython" />
        <input  class="buttongo" type="submit" value="Go" />
        <input type="hidden" name="task" value="getResult"/>
    </form>
</html>
```

Further, is there a way in which I can directly send the `value` to `index.php` and get the response?

(P.S.: I want to loop the `value` from `0` to `100` and save the response generated in a file)

Comment: please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Think of using %s in your code or try considering .format() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you send the request using python ? You can send the requests inside a loop and pass the parameters you want.

[Making requests with the requests module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/)

sample code :

```
import requests

for i in range(101):
    payload = {'usn': i}
    response = requests.post("index.php", data=payload)
    # do something with response
```

Comment: its better to include the relevant code in your answer, if that website you linked goes down, your answer becomes useless.

Comment: Thanks @zxzak. Can you just explain a bit more how do I play with the `response` generated? can I use it as a string? I tried `print(response)`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: I got it, used `response.text`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `urllib` module, documentation at: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html

As described in the link, *this module provides a high-level interface for fetching data across the World Wide Web.*